# illegal characters in path error c#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to download a csv file from the following link but an exception "illegal characters in path error" is thrown at the last line. I believe it's the question mark sign in the link that messes up everything but I have to get it working.. Any suggestions?

```
string remoteUri = "download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=%40%5EDJI,aapl&f=o&e=.csv";
string fileName = "aapl.csv", myStringWebResource = null;
// Create a new WebClient instance.
WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient();
// Concatenate the domain with the Web resource filename.
myStringWebResource = remoteUri + fileName;
// Download the Web resource and save it into the current filesystem folder.
myWebClient.DownloadFile(myStringWebResource, fileName);
```

Comment: You could could just replace the question mark with another character...

Comment: Question marks are valid url characters.

Comment: This link could be helpful : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/146134/how-to-remove-illegal-characters-from-path-and-filenames

Comment: Why doesn't your uri start with protocol?

Comment: Cannot reproduce. The second argument for `DownloadFile()` is the path to download the file to, and that contains "aapl.csv" in your example. That path will not throw the reported exception.

Comment: I tried to replace the question mark with # and it's still not working

Comment: One more link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19932755/illegal-characters-in-path-error-when-downloading-csv-file

Comment: myStringWebResource is "download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=%40%5EDJI,aapl&f=o&e=.csvaapl.csv" which seems not correct.

Comment: @Will sure, but that still won't throw the given exception. A 404 WebException at best.

Comment: I think your problem is `myStringWebResource = remoteUri + fileName;`, just don't do that. Then replace the last line with `myWebClient.DownloadFile(remoteUri, fileName);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. Lets see your code.

```
// Dont forget the "http://". A lot of browser add it themselves but the WebClient doesnt.
string remoteUri = "download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=%40%5EDJI,aapl&f=o&e=.csv";

// I recommend to take the habitude to write each one in one line.
string fileName = "aapl.csv", myStringWebResource = null;

// Use the "using" keyword to dispose WebClient
WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient();

// Why are you doing this? Your url is working without. No need to concat here.
myStringWebResource = remoteUri + fileName;

// Download the Web resource and save it into the current filesystem folder.
myWebClient.DownloadFile(myStringWebResource, fileName);
```

Solution to test : (Demo on [.NETFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/UkvgsQ))

```
using System;
using System.Net;

public class Program
{
    public void Main()
    {
        string remoteUri = "http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=%40%5EDJI,aapl&f=o&e=.csv";

        using (var myWebClient = new WebClient())
        {
            string csv = myWebClient.DownloadString(remoteUri);
            Console.WriteLine(csv);
        }   
    }
}
```

Solution to your problem :

```
using System;
using System.Net;

public class Program
{
    public void Main()
    {
        string remoteUri = "http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=%40%5EDJI,aapl&f=o&e=.csv";
        string fileName = "aapl.csv";

        using (var myWebClient = new WebClient())
        {
            myWebClient.DownloadFile(remoteUri, fileName);
        }   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This works:

```
string remoteUri = @"http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=%40%5EDJI,aapl&f=o&e=.csv";
string fileName = @"c:\aapl.csv";

// Create a new WebClient instance.
WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient();       

// Download the Web resource and save it into the current filesystem folder.
myWebClient.DownloadFile(remoteUri, fileName);
```

Comment: Dont forget to dispose the WebClient. See my answer.